# Non-interactive MySQL 8 installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, mysql

I am looking for a MySQL 8 installation using a script without any user action. I see that it's going to UI where I need to give password.
I tried:

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

I tried

```
echo " y 0 password password y y y y y y"| sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

but still, it's not working.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you get some error messages? Please edit your question to include them. And not post them as comments.

Comment: I dont get any error message. I get a popup UI to enter password. I am looking to make it automation